# Why are headers so wide

Tags: html, css, web, position

I have a part of a webpage which displays some words around the page. This section is supposed to take up 100% of the window space. This is the code:

```
<div id = "page" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color:black;">
    <header class = "words" style = "color:white; position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <h1 id = "cool" style = "position: relative; top: 20.62%; left: 11.55%;">ASSURED</h1>
        <h1 id = "nice" style = "position: relative; top: 39.18%; left: 31.61%;">ENIGMATIC</h1>
        <h1 id = "smart" style = "position: relative; top: 50.52%; left: 64.44%;">INTELLIGENT</h1>
        <h1 id = "intelligent" style = "position: relative; top: 67.53%; left: 48.63%;">SOPHISTICATED</h1>
        <h1 id = "peace" style = "position: relative; top: 77.32%; left: 20.67%;">CALM</h1>
    </header>    
</div>
```

However, even though each word is displayed fine, the whole webpage is moving to the left and pressing ctrl A the highlighting of each word is going miles to the right beyond the last letter and I can scroll to the right into "emptiness", which I obviously do not want.

Comment: Try removing all that positioning...it's a very poor layout method. Better options exist. See [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: You should change font-size, respectively, too. Also, as a side note: not sure that multiple h1 tags are actually valid... E.g. maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/haumxg6u/

Comment: Can I use relative for the top and absolute for the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem. I want to say 2 things.

1. Frankly, the way you have written the code is not recommended. It is not the proper way of writing it. You should use css classes. (Inline css is not a good practice)
2. Coming back to your problem, as you are not setting any width to these `<h1>` block elements, it is taking its own width or whole block to display the items. Until you use `width`(in your case width works) and `floats/inline-block`, you will get this kind of problems.

Refer: http://learnlayout.com/position.html